# What is causing this inconsistency between real mobile and desktop responsive design view with the same dimensions?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, tailwind-css, navbar, lottie

#### Pics of the issue

[Mobile view on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfGBM.png)

[Desktop with responsive design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBpQh.png)

As you can see from the photos, the logo on the mobile view is significantly pushed to the right, and I'm having trouble identifying the problem or coming up with a hacky solution since fixing the mobile version will break the desktop at low widths.

#### Nav bar with logo

```
        <nav
          className={`flex ${styles.paddingX} py-5 justify-between items-center navbar text-lg sticky      top-0 w-full z-50 max-h-24 bg-Background `}
        >
          <div className={"relative -left-16 h-[5.5rem]"}>
            <HashLink smooth to="/#home">
              <Logo />
            </HashLink>
          </div>
```

#### logo component

```
  render() {
    return (
      <lottie-player
        ref={this.myRef} // 2. set the reference for the player
        id="logo"
        mode="normal"
        src="https://lottie.host/f3af87e9-e5f9-4348-9f47-8c6f531e5377/9MB52b8b5v.json"
      ></lottie-player>
    );
  }
}
```

I also have this in the `<head>` but that did not solve the issue

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

#### Additional info/things I've tried

- I unfortunately need to use relative positioning since that allows me to offset the logo animation so it can come in from the edge of the screen while making sure the logo sits in the correct spot when the animation is done. Additionally I've tried other positioning modes that support offset like fixed and absolute but they still suffer from the same right shifting and dodon'tork as well with my current setup.
- I've viewed the website in landscape on my phone which takes it out of the mobile break point but the issue still persists so it's not a break point issue.
- I'm using modzilla dev tools but the issue exists in chrome too.